# Gitlab - Is it possible to display Trigger variables on Pipeline page

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have created a gitlab pipeline which get used to build and test the package. I am passing some parameters as an input. This Pipeline has been triggered around 200 times a day.

If I want to check the input parameters of any particular pipeline then I have to open any stage of that pipeline and check the Trigger variables.

Is it possible to display those variable on Pipelines page?

Below is the image where I want to display Trigger Variables.

[image: Pipeline page where I want to display Trigger Parameters]

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there's a way to see the trigger variables in the UI of the pipeline page.

You can add the `env` command in any job in the pipeline to see the env variables being passed/used/available in the job.

Here's a link to an example:
https://gitlab.com/kofisis/mult-stage-test/-/jobs/4794364474#L22

I hope this helps

Comment: The given link is not available (404 error). Can you please reshare the link